# с++ округляет деление

Tags: c++

Не могу понять причину, почему при делении вещественных чисел результат сам по себе округляется до 5 знаков после запятой.

Например:

При коде

```
double a = 115;
double b = 34;
double result = a / b;
cout << result << setprecision(11) << endl;
```

вывод будет

```
- 3,38235
```

хотя на калькуляторе

```
- 3,3823529411764705882352941176471
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы получить результат с точностью до 11-й цифры после запятой?

В Visual Studio данные числа не считает до 11-й цифры после запятой, в MingW
считает, но при делении на 3 MingW тоже округляет, из-за чего я в недоумении.

Comment: Задавать точность надо до вывода значения, а не после.

Answer (score 7):

Вместо

```
cout << result << setprecision(11) << endl;
```

используйте

```
cout << setprecision(11) << result << endl;
```

так как `setprecision(11)` выполняться для *следующих* элементов.

(Поток течет в направлении `<<`, т.е. справа налево в `cout` - сначала должно втечь в него `setprecision(11)`, после него `result` и наконец `endl`.)